# Updating vs Overwriting items from Staging Tables in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a `table` of aggregated data in DynamoDB that is populated from quality-checked data from `staging_table`.

I have **several scripts** that perform a scan in `staging_table` (all items), do some sort of calculation or verification and potentially need to insert/update an attribute from those staging items, before finally transferring them to the actual `table`. Note that this full scan happens various times, because each quality check procedure is independent from the others, but they happen in parallel.

What set of DynamoDB operations are best used here in terms of cost and performance? More objectively, the initial alternatives I thought of are:

- Use batch item writes to overwrite the old versions of the data (because `PutItem` is the only batch operation available)
- Use sequential `UpdateItem` operations (many more API calls, but each one less expensive)

Is there a better way? Is this scenario just not a good fit for DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution will depend on what is important to you;

- The monetary cost of your operation
- Latency between data hitting your staging table and being available in the main table
- Simplicity

[BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) consumes the same number of [write capacity units](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html) as PutItem and UpdateItem, so the monetary cost is the same.

BatchWriteItem should reduce latency between your staging table and main table (compared to PutItem or UpdateItem), but it comes at the cost of simplicity as you cannot have more than 25 items in your batch, each item cannot be more then 400KB, and the total batch cannot be more than 16MB. So you have a little more code to write. If you are hitting these limits you can create smaller batches, or consider writing your own parallel threading model with PutItem or UpdateItem.

You can potentially decrease latency by increasing your table RCUs and WCUs. You would need to optimise these for your particular operation between the two tables.

Minimising your writing time is only likely to be important if it is significant compared to your read/analysis time though. If it takes one minute to do your Scan and one second to do subsequent writes with UpdateItem, there is very little point in using batchwriteitem.

I would suggest you will see little or no difference between PutItem or UpdateItem. They consume the same number of WCUs so assuming you are throughput limited, there will be no difference.

One thing to consider is that [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) is not read consistent by default, meaning the table may change between the start and end of the Scan. Depending on your quality scans, you may want to set ConsistentRead to true.

I think ideally you would prototype the process using the most simple approach, and then analyse the solution to see which bits take significant time. You can then look to optimise those parts of the process.

Comment: Makes sense that `PutItem` and `UpdateItem` won't change much because of equal WCUs, but I thought that `UpdateItem` would write less data (only the new fields) instead of the whole Item. But you're right, I'll start with `UpdateItem` and try `BatchWriteItem` if necessary.